# Lazy load a module with empty path

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following setup:

```
app-module (root module)
    +frontend-module
    +backend-module
    auth-module
```

The frontend module should be responsible for the following paths:

```
/
/overview
/settings
/help
```

The backend module for all paths like this:

```
/backend/**
```

And the auth module for those paths:

```
/sign-in
/sign-up
/sign-out
```

If a user is not logged in, he should always be redirected to `/sign-in`.

Like you can see above, I want the frontend and backend module to load lazily. So whenever a user enters the website, it should load quite quickly, since the auth module is very lightweight. If he then enters his name and password, he should get redirected to `/overview`, which is in the frontend module (it should get loaded lazily then).

---

My problem is, that I can't get the lazy loading of the frontend module to work. I tried the following:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: 'backend',
                loadChildren: 'app/+backend/backend.module#BackendModule',
                canLoad: [AdminAuthGuardService]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: 'app/+frontend/frontend.module#FrontendModule',
                canLoad: [AuthGuardService]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

The routing config of the auth module is eagerly loaded, and defines the paths mentioned above (without any guard). But since the guard of the frontend module is defined as the empty path, it will assume that `/sign-in` is also part of the frontend module. The backend module works as expected.

---

Is it even possible to accomplish this somehow?

Another thing which could be a problem is that the root module doesn't even know which paths valid, so with the current setup it would have to load the frondend module anyway, so that it can verify the pathes, or am I wrong?

---

For explanation: My idea was to respond quickly if the user is not authed, in such way that the auth module is loaded immediately. After angular has done its work, I would have issued the load of the frontend module. So while the user is busy logging in, the actual application would load in the background

Any ideas / suggestions / best practices are welcome. But I really don't want to hack. If angular does not offer this, I will submit a feature request where this use case could be discussed further, but I don't want to make this possible at any price

Comment: Did you resolve this issue. I am facing the same issue. after angular-cli upgrade to **1.0.0-rc** getting error `ERROR in Cannot read property loadChildren' of null`

Comment: I am sorry, I was not able to solve this yet... Since this question was ignored, I decided to work on more important issues